# WaterMark TextBox in MVC Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I create a watermark on an HTML textbox? This is an MVC3 web application.

Answer (score 6):

If you can use HTML5, you can try the new placeholder attribute

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Field, new { placeholder = "Watermark here" })
```

It's pure HTML equivalent:

```
<input type="text" name="Field" id="Field" placeholder="Watermark here" />
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Does this jsfiddle works? http://jsfiddle.net/hejsh/

Answer (score 2):

Not specifically for MVC (this is script anyway), but since you're probably using jQuery in your MVC app anyway, you can use a JQuery plugin, like [Watermark](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/watermark).

Answer (score 0):

With this jquery you can show watermark on your text box .Here I am using an image in place of watermark.You need to create an image of the watermark text.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            /*Watermark for date fields*/

             if ($("#dob").val() == "") {
                $("#dob").css("background", "#ebebeb url('/Content/images/DateWaterMark.png') no-repeat 1px 0px");
            }

            $("#dob").focus(function () {
                if (watermark == 'MM/DD/YYYY') {
                    $("#dob").css("background-image", "none");
                    $("#dob").css("background-color", "#fff");
                }
            }).blur(function () {
                if (this.value == "") {
                    $("#dob").css("background", "#ebebeb url('/Content/images/DateWaterMark.png') no-repeat 1px 0px");
                }
            });

            $("#dob").change(function () {
                if (this.value.length > 0) {
                    $("#dob").css("background", "#fff");
                }
            });
}
```